# Why does Perl and /bin/sha1 give different results?

Tags: perl, sha1

I'm confused as to why the following return separate sHA1s

```
$ perl -MDigest::SHA1 -E'say Digest::SHA1::sha1_hex("http://i.aultec.com/v/8066/Originals/1FTVX12585NA9832010.jpg");'
e1133fa3b7ea0bfb8ffa4d877932ed6c6fa10cef

$ echo "http://i.aultec.com/v/8066/Originals/1FTVX12585NA9832010.jpg" | sha1sum 
5c3731e83ae0184ed93b595b9f5604863dd331e6  -
```

Which one is right? Am /I/ doing it wrong?

```
$ perl -MDigest::SHA -E'say Digest::SHA::sha1_hex("http://i.aultec.com/v/8066/Originals/1FTVX12585NA9832010.jpg");'
e1133fa3b7ea0bfb8ffa4d877932ed6c6fa10cef
```

You can see the digest is right in the successor (`Digest::SHA`)

Comment: In these cases, always look at the strings before you give them to the next step to ensure they are the same thing before you do the digest. Save it to a file and hexdump it if you have to.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both are right. Your echo command includes a newline at the end. (and the perl string doesn't) Try with `echo -n ...`

Answer (score 9):

Perl is giving you the hash of the literal string you entered, whereas echo is appending a newline.  If you tell `echo` to not add a newline, you'll get the same result:

```
drewfus:~$ perl -MDigest::SHA1 -E'say Digest::SHA1::sha1_hex("foo");'
0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33
drewfus:~$ echo -n "foo" | sha1sum
0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33  -
```

Answer (score 3):

This is such a frequent mistake and I've made it many times. The echo command is also returning a newline.

Comment: echo is not "returning" a newline.  It is outputting a newline, and (probably) returning 0.